# Best way to implement "dashboard" within custom list?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

My dashboard in this case is simply a waterfall of roughly 60 activities that need to be completed for each item. Ideally, people will be able to switch to the dashboard content type to see the status of each activity for each item.

Each item already has several content types representing "tabs" for their respective areas.

Each activity needs a status and optional comments.

We're using SP Foundation 2010, and I'm only a site owner (sucks, I know).

There must be a better way than just making a bunch of columns, then adding them to the "dashboard" content type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure what you mean by "roughly 60 activities", but if all you need to do are display some links or images, you could create an html page with links to your "activities" and load it into a content editor web part.  You need to save your html page somewhere in the site-collection libraries, and then the CEWP can display it seemlessly without any iframe.

Then, you can edit the html however you want, and no matter what page it appears on, the edit is made for everywhere you've used it.

You should be able to do this with Sharepoint Foundation.